# Wrong javascript function called when ascx control added to page twice

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have a control that contains a javascript function that is called on the client click event of a button:

```
OnClientClicked="ClearTree"
```

the function:

```
    function ClearTree() {
        var tree = $find('<%=cboOrgUnits.Items[0].FindControl("tvOrgUnits").ClientID %>');
        var nodes = tree.get_nodes();
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.get_count(); i++) {
            nodes.getNode(i).uncheck();
        }
   };
```

Which all works fine except for when the control is on the same page twice. When it is there are 2 instances of the function 'ClearTree' of which it seems the second one added is always called.

The problem is that the instance of ClearTree() called might not be referencing the correct tree.

What are the possible workarounds for this?

Here is the rest of the markup:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="cboOrgUnits" runat="server" Width="400px" ShowToggleImage="True" Style="vertical-align: middle;" EmptyMessage="Choose organisation units to group by" ExpandAnimation-Type="None" CollapseAnimation-Type="None">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <div>
        <span class="right" style="margin:2px"><telerik:RadButton ID="rbClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" Visible="True" OnClientClicked="ClearTree" AutoPostBack="False"/></span>
        <span class="right" style="margin:2px"><telerik:RadButton ID="rbDone" runat="server" Text="Done" Visible="True" OnClick="rbDone_Click"/></span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <div>
        <telerik:RadTreeView ID="tvOrgUnits" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" Style="z-index: 100" CheckChildNodes="True">
            <Nodes>
            </Nodes>
        </telerik:RadTreeView>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
<Items>
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="" />
</Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of embedding the `ClientID` of the control inside your function, make it a function parameter, and then change your `OnClientClicked` to pass the `ClientID` to the function.

```js
function ClearTree(id)
{
    var tree = $find(id);
    // ...
}
```

```csharp
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    rbClear.OnClientClicked = String.Format("ClearTree('{0}')", rbClear.ClientID);
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

**UPDATE:** Because `rbClear` is defined inside a template, you might need to call `cboOrgUnits.FindControl("rbClear")` to get a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I was trying to pass it through as a parameter but using inline code, with out much luck.